# Trazas de seguridad en Django

Tags: django

Quisiera saber como Django gestiona las trazas de seguridad, es decir, el registro de lo que hizo cada usuario para tener un mejor control de lo que se hace en la aplicación...

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia. La respuesta corta es que no lo hace, pero en el código fuente puedes encontrar algunas [pistas](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L17) y en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now). Pero claro, a menos que expongas un problema real con un __[mcve]__ esta pregunta podría ser cerrada.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es una solicitud de búsqueda no un problema real y concreto de programación.